# How to show a variable value on the webcam video stream? (python OpenCV)

Tags: python, webcam, opencv

I coded to open webcam video on a new window using OpenCV `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`.

You can display text on webcam video using `cv2.putText()` command. But it displays string values only.

How to put varying values in the webcam video that is being displayed on a new window?

For example, if value of variable `p` is changing all the time, you can easily display it on the command window by writing `print(p)`.
But how can we display values of `p` over the webcam video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also show changing variables using `cv2.putText()` method. Just need to convert the variable into string using `str()` method. Suppose you want to show variable `x` that is for example an integer and it is  always changing. You can use `cv2.putText(frame, str(x), org, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)`  to do it (You should fill `org`,`font`, etc.).

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!
I TRIED TO UPVOTE, BUT THEY WONT LET ME BECAUSE I AM NEW